# Loading an KeyStore make problems

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore

I have a problem loading a KeyStore with a keypair that has a different password than the KeyStore.

With the following code, I try to load the KeyStore:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("src\\integrationTest\\test.p12"))) {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12","BC");
        keyStore.load(inputStream, "test".toCharArray());
    }
```

The Following Exception is thrown on Runtime:

```
java.io.IOException: exception unwrapping private key - java.security.InvalidKeyException: pad block corrupted
```

Answer (score 0):

@Novaax

Did you validate the certificate p12 with Keytool Command

> keytool -list -v -keystore cert.pfx -storepass